# Get access to spinner options UI

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm building an Android activity that will work sort of like a tutorial. Ideally I would like to have a spinner that simulates making a selection. It will look as if someone is clicking on it and making a selection, but the user will simply watch and not be allowed to interact.

I've got to the point where I've disabled user interaction using `setClickable(false)` and opened the options using `performClick()`.

This is where I'm stuck. I don't seem to be able to access the new UI that appears with the options listed. I need to disable user interaction and programatially select one of them.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a requestFocus on the Spinner and then sending keystrokes to it.

Comment: Interesting idea. How would I "send keystrokes" to it?